# Type '{ componentParent: this; }' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<RegisterEnterpriseComponent>' angular

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, components

i am using angular 10, i am trying to do show a modal in my component, but i get this error:

```
Type '{ componentParent: this; }' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<RegisterEnterpriseComponent>'
```

Code:

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(
    public modalService: BsModalService, public mybsModalRef: BsModalRef) { 
  }

openModal(id) {
    const initialState = {
      componentParent: this
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(RegisterEnterpriseComponent, {initialState}); // The error is in this line
    this.bsModalRef.setClass('modal-lg'); 
    this.EnterpriseService.closeModal = this.bsModalRef;
  }
```

I have used this function before with angular 8, but i dont know why is not working in this version of angular...

Anyone can help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please tell us more about this `modalService`? This is some library from npm, something that is build-in or it is your service? And just to be sure - what you passing is `, { initialState: { componentParent: this }}`, are you sure you shouldnt pass just `RegisterEnterpriseComponent, initialState`? This is just guessing right now.

Comment: @FaustynPiechowiak Sorry, i haven´t specified what modalService is, so i edited the question, the modalService is the BsModalService from ngx-boostrap, the objetive is to open a modal with that function.. And yes, when i pass { initialState: { componentParent: this }} in angular 8 it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

If someone is facing the same problem, in newer versions of ngx-bootstrap the arguments required doesn´t need the initialParent anymore:

I just had to put it in this way:

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(RegisterEnterpriseComponent);
```

And it works without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can only specify properties that actually exist on the `RegisterEnterpriseComponent` component you are using for the modal, so  `this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(RegisterEnterpriseComponent, { initialState: {test: ''} });`  would not give an error if your `RegisterEnterpriseComponent` component contains the property `test`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const config = {
  class: 'modal-dialog-centered',
  initialState: {
    id,
    name: this.productTypes.find((p) => p.id === id).name,
  },
};
//show modal
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(
  AddModalProductTypeComponent,
  config
);
//get data in modal 
export class AddModalProductTypeComponent implements OnInit {
@Output() newProductType = new EventEmitter<any>();
id: number;
name: string;
```

}